# Read and Write Disk Drive registers as Read Only

Tags: disk, burning

I am having an issue were my read write disk drive is being registered by my system as "Read Only" I know its capable of burning disks because its done it before when it ran on my previous OS. How do I get the the Disk Drive to burn disks again and register as Read and Write? When I do get to a burn I will see a the Blank Disk option (read and write) but it is unselectable.

Lenovo X300
4 Gb RAM
Dual Core/ Intel Centrinos
Read/Writable Disk Drive

Comment: You mean a CD/DVD drive? What program are you using to burn the CD/DVD?

Comment: Do you need a program to burn something to a disk? Most OS's come with that feature. Does Linux?

Comment: Wait no, I use Linux Image Writer but it doesn't register my CD Drive as writable and the it will take me to a folder called burn:/// then it says unable to find directory.

Comment: Burning a CD/DVD is *very* different from writing to a harddisk. Linux could write directly to a CD-burner long ago, but they removed this "feature", because in most cases that's not what you want. I'm not familiar with Linux Image Writer. The usual steps to burning a data CD/DVD are first to make the image (so you can verify), and then burn it. There are a quite a few programs to burn, or to add a GUI to other programs; try some of these (google).